# Positioning all class elements to align from the same point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to position my div with the class `.content-window` so that they all align from the same point, which is the top left corner of the first `section` element.

This is the first time I've encountered this problem and I've tried everything, from pure CSS to JQUERY.

Here's the JSFiddle for the project : http://jsfiddle.net/smpte11/SahM8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap is setting your `<section>`s to `position: relative`. You'll need to manually override that and position the rest of your elements accordingly.

Here's one way to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/SahM8/1/

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I was wondering how you did it in case it happens in the future. I can't seem to figure out what is new and what is old.

Also, you said that it was one way to do it. Was it the quickest? Are there more efficient methods?

Comment: I used firebug to inspect the parent elements until I found one what had `position: relative` (or `absolute`) set. If a parent element has either of those set, child elements with `position: absolute` will base their top/right/bottom/left from that element.

Comment: I do see my mistake now! Just have a couple of things to figure out now but it almost works perfectly! Thank you again!